# Handling a sequence in a series: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(a_n)^n \cos(n\pi)}{n}$ for $a_n \rightarrow \tfrac{1}{2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The question is whether the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(a_n)^n \cos(n\pi)}{n}$, where  $\{ a_n \}$ is a sequence of positive numbers that converges to ½, converges absolutely or not.

My hesitation is that we know nothing about the behaviour of $a_n$ (whether it is strictly increasing/decreasing or oscillatory). Here is what I am thinking, but I'm uncertain if it is sufficiently attentive to details:

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(a_n)^n\cos(n\pi)}{n} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(a_n)^n(-1)^n}{n}$

We're interested in absolute convergence, so we consider the absolute value of that series, viz:

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(a_n)^n}{n}$

Case I: Assume $a_n \rightarrow ½$ from above, then there exists some $n > N$ such that $a_n < r$, where $r<1$, for all $n > N$. As such,

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=N}^{\infty} \frac{(a_n)^n}{n} < \sum_{n=N}^{\infty} \frac{(r)^n}{n} <   \sum_{n=N}^{\infty} r^n$,

which is a convergent geometric series because $r<1$.

&nd then similarly for for $a_n \rightarrow ½$ from below. Now that I think of it, we could probably handle the entire thing in one case by using absolute values, right?

Comment: Can't you just use Comparison Test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An approach.

Let $0<\epsilon<1$. Since $\left\{a_n\right\}_{n\geq1}$ converges to $\frac 12$, then 
$$
\exists \,N\geq0, \forall n\geq N, \left|a_n-\frac 12\right|\leq \epsilon.
$$
Taking for example $\epsilon:=\frac14$,
$$
|a_n|\leq\left|a_n-\frac 12\right|+\frac 12\leq\frac 34, \quad n\geq N,
$$
and
$$
|a_n|^n\leq\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{n}, \quad n\geq N.
$$
Then you may write
$$
\left|\sum_{n=N}^{\infty} \frac{(a_n)^n \cos(n\pi)}{n}\right|\leq \sum_{n=N}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{n}
$$
But on the right handside we have the rest of a convergent series, thus on the left handside the rest of our series may be as small as we want as $N$ is great.

The initial series is absolutely convergent.

Comment: This seems to use $|a|\leqslant b+c\implies|a|^n\leqslant2b^n+2c^n$... which is wrong.

Comment: @Did Oops, fixed. Thank you!

Comment: sorry for the delay in recognizing the solution - not sure what happened there. Thank you for the very clear proof!

Answer (score -3):

We know that $\{a_n\}$ is a sequence of strictly positive numbers that converges to $\frac{1}{2}$, so we can take the absolute value of the whole thing to get rid of the cosine term, and perform the Comparison Test with the series $${\sum_{n=1}^\infty} {a_n}^n$$ which is a geometric series for all $n > N $ for some $N$ and hence converges. We know that: 
$${\sum_{n=1}^\infty} \frac{{a_n}^n}{n} \leq {\sum_{n=1}^\infty} {a_n}^n$$
and the result should fall out. Obviously not the most rigorous proof, and you would need to elaborate on this argument, but that should be the general gist of it.

Comment: If $a_n\to\frac12$ then $\sum\limits_na_n$ *diverges*, not converges.

Comment: @ Did - Forgot to raise $a_n $ to the power of n, cheers

Comment: Another problem is that $\sum\limits_n(a_n)^n$ is *not* a geometric series.